# Spring Security call login programmatically

Tags: java, spring, security

I am developing an application and I am using Spring Security. My question is - is there a way to call the exact logic that is run when I send a post request to /login (default), but from within the programme?

Normally, I post my LoginUserDto object to /login endpoint to login. However, I am implementing facebook login now, so I am constructing my LoginUserDto on the server side from whatever data I get from facebook based on user's access token. Now I just need to call the same logic that I would normally call with the rest call to /login, but from within the code in order to return tokens.

Does anyone know how this can be done?
Thanks

Comment: why can't this be done in the controller method?

Comment: how? imagine I have a custom endpoint - /loginFB . Inside this endpoint I get facebook user data from facebook servers and map it to LoginUserDto. Now I need to call the logic of the "/login" endpoint that is normally auto-configured by spring secuirty. So what call should I make from within my custom /loginFB controller method ?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at Spring Security 5's inbuilt support for OAuth2, as this will be the easiest way to incorporate Facebook as an external Authorization Server.  There is some [good documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2login) which walks through what is necessary via OAuth2 Login.  Additionally, I found working with the [oauth2login sample code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples/boot/oauth2login) from the Spring Security Repository extremely helpful to understand how the application should be configured, and it has a section for integrating with Facebook.